# Expression Problem – looking for a similar standard problem

Tags: reference-request, programming-languages, software-engineering

The [Expression Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem), populated by Philip Wadler,  is a often used to standard problem to evaluate programming languages.

I think it is a very clear and popular example and I wonder if there are any similar standard problems that are possibly also as widely used and as clear.

So, are there any similar standard problems?

(In the case of Feature Oriented Programming ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_Oriented_Programming) [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOSD_Program_Cubes#Applications)) I found some standard problems, like:
- implementation of a stack with different features
- implementation of linked lists
- implementation of a calculator
- the graph product line
- stock broker and bank account examples
- hierarchical display
)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that the problem is formulated quite as nicely, but the problem of implementing concurrency in an efficient manner has occupied at least as much effort as the expression problem, and prompted a [number of solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_pattern), including the use of [semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) and [software transactional memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory).

I'm certainly not an expert, but I believe the problem of concurrency can be formulated in a similar manner to the expression problem: create language constructs which allow us to simultaneously:

1. Have sufficient expressivity to create complex concurrent programs, say, a web server.
2. Be able to have a reasonable assurance that these complex programs will not incur [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).